# increment operator-how to input increment varilable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to retrieve weather data through openweather API but when I try to do so I couldn't able to retrieve the forecast of the weather.

```
import json,requests,urllib.parse
url='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?'

while True:
    APPID='xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    id='1283378'

    main_url=url +urllib.parse.urlencode({'id':id}) +'&APPID=xxxxxxxxx'  
    response=requests.get(main_url).json()
    #print(main_url)

    status=response['cod']
    print(status + '\n')
    inc=0

if status =="200":
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        for each in response["list"][i]["weather"]:                                                     
                print(each["main"])
                date= response["list"][i]["dt_txt"]
                print(date)
```

How I could increment the value of `i`, so that the forecast data can be retrieved? `x+=` and `range` doesn't help here as `x+=` only can increment one value and `range` cannot be given as an input one by one.

Output of the above program is:

```
200

0
1
2
3
4
Clouds
2018-03-23 06:00:00
```

Comment: Your indentation looks funny (standard is 4 spaces only). Can you fix it so we have a chance at understanding your intended logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even really need `range(5)`:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(response["list"]):
    print(i)
    date = elem["dt_txt"]  # doesn't change as each changes
    for each in elem["weather"]:
        print(each["main"])
        print(date)
```

`range` is one of the more overused functions in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You need indentation:

```
if status =="200":
     for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        for each in response["list"][i]["weather"]:
            print(each["main"])
            date= response["list"][i]["dt_txt"]
            print(date)
```